# Why isn't the label of the check box hidden when I hide it?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a check box:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="OutOfPocket">Are you okay with paying out-of-pocket for these services?</input>
```

and I have some `jQuery` to hide it:

```
$('#OutOfPocket').hide();
```

but the problem is that line doesn't hide the label. So, I tried the following commands to hide the label but all have been unsuccessful:

```
$('#OutOfPocket').next('label').hide();
$('#OutOfPocket').siblings('label').hide();
$('#OutOfPocket').next('input ~ label').hide();
$('#OutOfPocket').next('span').hide();
$('#OutOfPocket').siblings('span').hide();
$('#OutOfPocket').next('input ~ span').hide();
```

what code do I need to hide the text of the check box?

Comment: Where is the label relative to the input?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, but why not just put both of them in a container and hide the container?

Comment: @Jace, it's next to the `input`, at the same level, based on the rendered HTML. If you place that HTML I provided on a blank page you'll see the label (i.e. the text of the check box) rendered next to it.

Comment: @xaxxon, I can, it just seemed to me that I could hide standard input element pretty simply using jQuery.

Comment: oh right... you're not actually using a `<label>`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `<input/>` doesn't support inner text like that. From [`<input>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input):

> Permitted content - None, this is a void element.

Although it may appear as a label with whatever browser you're using, you probably want to use an actual [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) for your label.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="OutOfPocket"/><label for="OutOfPocket">Are you okay with paying out-of-pocket for these services?</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Rob's answer, input tags are self-closing. For checkboxes, the value attribute is hidden. So you would indeed write the label after the input tag:

```
<input type="checkbox">Are you okay with paying out-of-pocket for these services?
```

In that case, you need to either wrap the thing in a container, ie a `span` tag, or to wrap the text in a label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label for="OutOfPocket">
<input type="checkbox" id="OutOfPocket"/>
  <span>Are you okay with paying out-of-pocket for these services?</span>
</label>
```

This allows checkbox to be checked when you click in text.

And allows to hide text easily:

```
$('label span').hide()
```